# bootstrap-select javascript instantiation does not create object

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

It seems that if I create the select and options fields via Javascript / jQuery, it will not create an instance of object selectpicker for the newly created object.
In the documentation i cannot find how to force an instanciation.

This is what my code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var content = $('<select class="selectpicker">'
    +'<option>STRING</option>'
    +'</select>');
    content.find('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

This is the error I get from the browser:

```
TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function


content.find('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

Includes are all correct, using it embedded in the normal HTML code works.

Someone tumbled already over this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure `bootstrap-select.min.js` is added after `jquery` but before your code.

remove the `find` as content is the `select`

```
var content = $('<select class="selectpicker">'
+'<option>STRING</option>'
+'</select>');
content.selectpicker();
```